# How to get score from text cells without complicated code in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

May I point to an issue which was that I don't know a possible way of recuperating the score in excel (out of 5), without being complicated with an abundance of ifs.

i.e. Is there a possible method to get the score out of this? (without using lots of ifs):

[image: Excel answers]

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/case.php

Comment: @techie007 Why use a VBA solution when Excel formulas can work just as well?

Comment: @bdr9 Because there's more than one way to skin a cat. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `CHOOSE` function in Excel should accomplish what you are trying to do.

From http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/choose-HP005209013.aspx:

> Uses index_num to return a value from the list of
>   value arguments. Use CHOOSE to select one of up to 29 values based on
>   the index number. For example, if value1 through value7 are the days
>   of the week, CHOOSE returns one of the days when a number between 1
>   and 7 is used as index_num.
>
> Syntax
>
> CHOOSE(index_num,value1,value2,...)
>
> Index_num specifies which value argument is selected. Index_num
>   must be a number between 1 and 29, or a formula or reference to a cell
>   containing a number between 1 and 29.

So, for example, if the correct answer were the second answer, you could use:

```
=CHOOSE(A1, "Incorrect", "Correct", "Incorrect, "Incorrect", "Incorrect")
```

And the function would return `Correct` only if cell `A1` contains `2`. However, `CHOOSE` only works with numbers. If your answers are given as letters, you could map A, B, C... to 1, 2, 3... with the following formula:

```
=CODE(UPPER(A1))-64
```

This converts the letter in cell `A1` to uppercase (if it isn't already uppercase), and then finds its ASCII code. ASCII codes for uppercase letters start at 65, so if we want the numbering to start at 1, we simply subtract 64.